# Cannot get video to play

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator

After having looked around SO on how to play a movie with Objective-C it seems to be quite straightforward. The code i'm using is the following:

```
- (void) createMovie {
    NSLog(@"create movie method called");
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"walkthrough" ofType:@"mp4"];   

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(184, 200, 400, 300);
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    [player play];

}
```

I have included the appropriate `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>` in my header file. When the view loads i can see a black box which i assume is the frame of the player view but no video. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving out `MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer` of your function. (Like the .h file or just above the function). Then do:

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

I think you are releasing it as soon as you leave the function.